# Getting the exact time a request was initiated

Tags: web, time, request

I would like to know if it is possible to differentiate the initiation time of a request in the milliseconds area.

Say I have 2 users that make a request at 40ms interval. Is they a way to know server-side the exact time of the initiation of the requests ?

According to me, using Http would mean there's no way to know exactly which request was initiated first. Maybe using websocket ? (My project is a website project)

Comment: Assuming that both client and server are synced for system time, can't the client just send a timestamp along with the request?

Comment: The problem with sending a timestamp is that they could be a way for a  bad intentioned user to send a false timestamp.

Comment: Even if you use a socket, you cannot assume in general that a have a response from computer A followed 40 msec latter by a response from B means that A actually even send the message first. Over the internet, packet delays can easily exceed 40 ms. There is no guarantee that packets are even received in same order they were submitted by a single machine at the UDP level.

Comment: Is they any protocol that would force the clients to send the real time ?